# cant get page source using bs4 and proxies

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, proxies

I wanna scrape

```
https://www.mscdirect.com
```

Using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
proxies = {'http': 'http://XXX:XXX@111.11.111.111:XXXX','https': 'http://XXX:XXX@111.11.111.111:XXXX'}
url ='https://www.mscdirect.com'
r2 = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
html = r2.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
print((soup.encode("utf-8")))
```

and this code works for the homepage of this website, I get the page source, but on other pages of this website this code doesn't works, I've got error like this:

```
  MSCdirect.com is currently not available for your use.\n
```

Comment: You are probably not sending correct headers, or using an incorrect protocol. You should monitor the GET requests directly from firefox, then try to find the correct headers or protocol with a software like postman.

Comment: i need to use hola VPN on m browser to open the page, without hola VPN i also see the same error message in my browser

Comment: Try using selenium. It will run all the javascript you need to display and get all what you need.

Comment: i tried and it doesn't worked